# Django Runserver crashes due to autoreload?

Tags: django, powershell

so i'm very new to Django. But my problem is as follows:
When I create a project, the runserver often won't start. I type:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Powershell freezes for a while and says: "Python is not responding"
The Problem does not appear when typing:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

I am using Windows 10 and Django 1.10.6 as well as Python 3.6
The problem has also been reported on the forum of djangoproject but there was no solution offered. Is there any way to fix this?

Will disableling autoreload affect working with the Localhost?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just started encountering this same bug tonight. I'm not sure how to fix it just yet or what causes it, but running with `--noreload` won't hurt anything. The server just won't reload when you make a Python change, so you'll have to restart the server yourself to test changes.

Comment: It is good to hear, that I dont seem to be alone with this problem. It is quite annoying since --noreload also stopped working for me. I'm quite desperate to find a solution for this. So if you have one, please let me know.

Comment: Put debug value to False in settings.py