# Python.exe crashes when I run manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

Before the problem occurred I was learning how to create projects and apps in Django. After I decided to remove the project folder and create a new project I have stacked on `runserver`. 
Before asking this question I have been trying to figure out the problem for few days. The only solution is to unistall+ install Python 3.6 and it works once only:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd d:\py\piglatin
PS D:\py\piglatin> python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly unti
 auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
March 19, 2017 - 01:44:42
Django version 1.10.6, using settings 'piglatin.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[19/Mar/2017 01:50:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1767
PS D:\py\piglatin> python manage.py runserver
PS D:\py\piglatin> python manage.py runserver
PS D:\py\piglatin> python manage.py runserver
```

I have done all migrations but still Python crashes.

Comment: `PS D:\py\piglatin> python manage.py check
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).`

Comment: did you try `python manage.py makemigrations ` before you migrated? Also did you try running your project in a virtualenv?

Comment: sure, I have mentioned that

Comment: It looks like you're on Windows with Powershell? Windows 10 by chance? It looks like maybe a few people have been reporting this. [Reported issue here - no resolution offered though](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27657) Try 'python manage.py runserver --noreload'

Comment: Also related post here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707586/django-runserver-crashes-due-to-autoreload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707586/django-runserver-crashes-due-to-autoreload)

Comment: Try opening your task manager and kill all running pythons

Comment: @laurenll it works with `--noreload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created a virtual environment? If so, go to your Scripts folder enter 'activate' or '.\activate'

This will allow you to run your server in a virtual environment without worrying about your local system dependencies interfering and will hopefully solve your issue.